# Is my neural network suffering from overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

I am trying to construct a multi-class neural network that predicts rock paper or scissors as accurately as possible from a data set I created.

As I messed around with various parameters, the training set's loss/accuracy seems to vary widely. However, after a lot of trial and error, this seems to be the best model version. I have looked over other questions relating to mine and I think these graphs seems appropriate, but being as I am a new to machine learning, I am wondering the model is suffering from some issue (over fitting/under fitting) that I am just not seeing.

I understand overfitting refers to the case where as epochs increase, accuracy goes up and the loss goes down, but I am still unsure if there is something obvious on the graph that is escaping my understanding.

This is how I'm currently compiling and fitting the model.

```
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy'], optimizer=Adam(.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=30, verbose=True, validation_split=.33, batch_size=3)
```

[Model Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrtGJ.png)

[Model Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wVIj.png)

Edit:

The model should predict either rock paper or scissors based upon previously decided coefficients being multiplied against 9 features.
5 features being randomly created coefficients representing the Big 5 Personality Dimensions ranging as continuous values from -2 to 2.

The other four are:

1. If they won or lost.

2, 3, 4) If they won choosing rock, paper, or scissors: and each of those three being multiplied against a coefficient that acts as the bias toward them winning.

The probability of choosing rock paper or scissors have an activation built in that gives a bias toward the respective choice. Scissors has the highest bias.

There are 999 trials (excluded the first since its due to random chance) and each of the 100 trial values, for the Big 5 Personality dimension, remain the same. Only the columns representing Won/Lost and won choosing rock, paper, or scissors change trial by trial.

Comment: Can you, as an "annotator" decide what the model should predict?  I would be concerned that there is no way to make an accurate prediction that is better than chance. Maybe you could clarify what the input features are like.

Comment: How is your data structured and what outcome are you predicting? How big is the data set?

Comment: Ah. Right, sorry. The model should predict either rock paper or scissors based upon previously decided coefficients being multiplied against 9 features. The largest drivers being a given bias toward scissors, if they won, and if they won choosing rock, paper or scissors. I'll update the question with this information as well.

999 trials (excluded the first since its due to random chance)

Comment: You concept of overfitting in this question is completely incorrect. Overfitting is defined only by looking at train/validation loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the loss and accuracy curve, it does seem like you've fitted your model to the training data very precisely (a sign of overfitting). If you're worried about the overfitting issue then you may adopt some regularization methods like L1/L2 regularizer (weight decay), Dropout, Batch Norm, etc. They will help the model generalize well to the unseen data. Also, methods like "early stopping" are also applicable in such a scenario. Hope it'll help you mitigate your issue of overfitting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into those methods.

Comment: Great! If it answered your question you may select it as your answer so that others may find it useful as well. Thanks

Comment: -1 "it does seem like you've fitted your model to the training data very precisely (a sign of overfitting)" overfitting is when you've fit your training data too precisely and it cannot generalize, so this is opposite definition.

Comment: "you've fitted your model to the training data very precisely" - "overfitting is when you've fitted your training data too precisely" If you could elaborate what you meant, I find both our sentence's semantic meaning the same...

Comment: Overfitting is when the training loss is low, and the validation/test loss is high in comparison, having almost zero training loss does not tell you anything alone about overfitting.

Comment: Indeed. If you see both curves, the validation loss curve has saturated at quite an early stage and does not improve  (rather drops at some point) whilst the training loss is getting quite closer to zero, in this case, the model is very likely going to learn all the quirks and noises of the training set very very well. If that training set isn't a very good representative of the true distribution (which most of the time is the case), then early stopping is the way to go (to prevent overfitting).

Comment: Khalid, I'd like to up vote your answer but being as my reputation score is so low, it won't allow me. My apologies - I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: No worries, however, there's a "checkmark/tick" option for you as the questioner to select any question as an answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. So you can do that if it answers your problem.